# Unable to paste and clear contents of cell

Tags: vba, excel

**Here is my code:**

```
For j = 3 To 37 Step 2
If PaddleBDateInstalledTextBox.Value = Cells(j, 8).Value Then
        Cells(j, 8).Copy
        Range("D42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Range("D42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Range("D42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme '<-- 
        cells background, etc.
        Range("D42").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YY"
        Cells(j, 8).Clear
 End If
Next
```

I have one cell where the format is a date and I am trying to copy it first and then paste it into another cell but my cell did not have the value pasted in it and the original cell; and the contents were not cleared.

I have another cell that has the format `Today()` and I want to just copy the value without the formula into another cell but i have failed as well.

The last cell that I want to copy has a formula of `=($I$2-H2)+(G2-F2)` and I have the same problem.

Comment: You say _I want to just copy the value without the formula into another cell_  so you should _not_ use `Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`.  If you delete that line does it work?

Comment: So i tried this given your recommendation unfortunately the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
If 1 = Cells(1, 1).Value Then 'Assuming in Cell(1, 1) is the value 1
    Cells(1, 1).Copy
    Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme

    Range("B1").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YY"
    Cells(1, 1).Clear
End If
```

Maybe the `Cells(j, 8).Value` is your problem. What value does `j` have? If `j` is a variable your code should be right, but if you mean `J` as column name the code should be `Range("J" & 8).Value` or `Cells(8, "J").Value` instead of `Cells(j, 8).Value`

Comment: yes the j is defined as an integer variable and it is used in a for loop to extract values in each 2nd cell of the column. I have edited the post to include the for loop. I was able to use the same code if the cell only had values that are integers or strings but with formats such as dates and formulas i was unable to clear contents of the cell and paste the contents of the cell after copying.